# Negativity of contraction

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $f:X\to Y$ be a birational morphism, $X, Y$ projective, $X$ smooth (threefold if this helps). Let $Exc(f)\subseteq X$ be the exceptional locus of $f$ and let $E\subseteq Exc(f)$ be an irreducible divisor. Is it true that for any curve $C\subseteq E$ contracted by $f$ one has $C\cdot E<0$? I can see this is true if $C$ is not contained in any other divisor sitting in $Exc(f)$, but what if it is?

Comment: In the case where X is $P^2$ blown up in two points, the two exceptional divisors $E_1$ and $E_2$ satisfy your hypothesis but as they are distinct curves, you have necessairly $(E_1 \cdotp E_2) \geq 0$. Or am I wrong?

Comment: Yes $E_1\cdot E_2=0$, but the assumptions of the question are not satisfied  here. In fact, the question does have an affirmative answer for surfaces using Mumford's about negative definiteness of the intersection matrix.

Comment: Mumford's ^result (I wish I could edit comments).

Comment: To be more explicit, $E$ is supposed to be irreducible and $C\subseteq E$, which implies $E=C$, when $X$ is a surface. So $C^2 <0$ by
Mumford.

Comment: Ok, I didn't notice the irreducibility of the divisor $E$, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dear Carlos, the statement is false in general. For example let $Y$ be $\mathbb{C}^3$, let $f_1 : X_1 \rightarrow Y$ be the blowup of a point on $Y$, and $f_2 : X \rightarrow X_1$ the blowup of a point on the exceptional divisor of $f_1$. Let $f : X \rightarrow Y$ be the composition. The exceptional locus of $f$ has two components: a copy $F$ of $\mathbb{P}^2$ (the exceptional divisor of $f_2$) and a copy $E$ of the blowup of $\mathbb{P}^2$ in one point (the strict transform of the exceptional divisor of $f_1$). The intersection $C = E \cap F$ is a copy of $\mathbb{P}^1$, it is a line on $F$ and the $f_2$-exceptional curve on $E$. Now $E \cdot C$ equals $C^2$ computed on $F$ (because $C=E \cap F$),
so $E \cdot C = +1$.